# a problem with Stokes' theorem(curl)

Tags: integration, conic-sections, surfaces

If L is the circle which you get from the intersection between the sphere $$ x^2+y^2+z^2=1, y=x\sqrt(3) $$
and $$  I= \int_L (y-z)dx+(z-x)dy+(x-y)dz $$
so |I| equals to?

but i dont understand how the intersection is a circle
if i compare between them im getting  $$ 4x^2+z^2=1 $$
but this thing is an ellipse
what am i doing wrong?

Comment: The intersection looks like an ellipse if you look at it from the side owing to the tilt of the intersecting plane. But it'll be a circle if you look at it 'head on.'

Comment: @Semiclassical can you further explain

Comment: You might wish to add a 'conic sections' tag to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Your confusion arises because the equations of conic sections in 2D and 3D are different.
It is not enough to write $4x^2+z^2=1$ to specify an ellipse in 3D - in fact, that is the equation of a cylinder with an elliptical cross-section, and the y-axis as cylinder axis. However, if you add $y=0$, it becomes an ellipse.

Now imagine cutting this elliptic cylinder with a plane. If you use planes parallel to the xz plane by picking a constant y, you'll get ellipses. But if you cut the elliptic cylinder with a plane of just the right inclination to the xz plane you can actually specify a circle in space.

Comment: great, thanks, 
but i still cant manage to solve this problem
cant you show me how to?(at least the very beginning)

Comment: i think i  got it
is it right to say that the integral equals to:$$ rotF*n =-(2i+2j+2k)*(\sqrt(3),0,0) $$